# geb cant find checkbox element

Tags: groovy, element, geb

there is this piece of code that provides a checkbox following from a link to the T&C.

```
<div class="checkbox accept_agreement">
<label class="control-label" for="step_data_accept_agreement">
<input type="hidden" name="step_data[accept_agreement]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="step_data[accept_agreement]" id="step_data_accept_agreement" value="1">

<label for="step_data_accept_agreement">
<a target="_blank" href="/lanevillkor/">
<font><font>I agree, have read and stored the terms and conditions</font></font>
</a>
</label>
</label>
</div>
```

Now, I am working on a spock test using geb, and I try to retrieve the checkbox element

```
<input type="checkbox" name="step_data[accept_agreement]" id="step_data_accept_agreement" value="1">
```

to do so i have tried many things without the expected output. i was expected that something like

`$("#step_data_accept_agreement").click()` would be pretty straight forward but it is not. in the other side if I put $`("[for='step_data_accept_agreement'] label").click()` it clicks the link.

I tried to become as more specific but nothing looks to return the element correctly. 
one of my last attempts was

```
termsAndConditionsOption(wait: true) { $("#step_data_accept_agreement", name: "step_data[accept_agreement]") }
```

and the error message, as in the other cases too, was in one sentence

> element not visible

What do I miss?

Comment: I had similar issue, I had 2 elements with the same ID, the click didn't work because I clicked the wrong element. Try to see how many elements `$("#step_data_accept_agreement")` returns

Comment: Which driver are you using? Do you get an exception when you try to click that checkbox or does nothing happen? If you get an exception can you please paste the stacktrace? There's always Geb's [`CheckboxModule`](http://gebish.org/manual/current/#checkbox-module) that aims at making checking checkboxes easy.

Comment: thanks for your responses. To answer back to each comment: 1. $("#step_data_accept_agreement") doesnt return anything. In fact seems that the element is not visible. 2. @erdi Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to take a look on CheckboxModule for sure. however I came up with a different solution.

Comment: Royg probably wanted to know what `$('#step_data_accept_agreement').size()` returns...

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to use js to click the checkbox. The simpliest way is:

```
def agreeOnTermsAndConditionsAccept() {

        String mouseClickEvt = """
                var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    cancelable: true,
                    view: window
                });
                arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
        """
        browser.js.exec(termsAndConditionsOption.firstElement(), mouseClickEvt)

    }
```

Geb provides js support to work with javascript, as we find in the documentation. Also another [link](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-simulate-a-click-event-with-javascript/) shows how to simulate a click event with pure javascript.

This was required as the checkbox cant be found as it is hidden. With javascript we can 'see' the position of the element and perform an action in the location that we want. iniMouseEvent can be used as well as it is documentanted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent)